# sql stored function gives an error

Tags: sql, error-handling, firebird, firebird-3.0

I am trying to create a stored function to take one parameter called budget. The function should return the string 'LOW' for a budget less than or equal to 500000, 'MID' for a budget less than or equal to 850000, 'HIGH' for a budget less than or equal to 1200000, and 'ULTRA' for a budget above 1200000. But I am getting an error that doesn't make much sense to me.

Here is my function:

```
set term # ;

create procedure f_rating(budget int) 
as
begin
if (budget <= 500000) then
    return ('LOW');
else if (budget <= 850000) then
    return ('MID');
else if (budget <= 1200000) then
    return ('HIGH');
else 
    return ('ULTRA');
end #
```

I am still new to sql, so this syntax is based on examples online and such. Here is my error:

```
SQL Message : -804
An error was found in the application program input parameters for the SQL statement.

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -804
Function unknown
RETURN
```

Can anyone help me figure out what this means?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: I am using Flamerobin Database admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax for stored function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-ddl-func-create) is

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcname [ ( [ <in_params> ] ) ]
  RETURNS <domain_or_non_array_type> [COLLATE collation]
  [DETERMINISTIC]
  <module-body>
```

So you have made two mistakes, you use `procedure` instead of `function` and you miss the `RETURNS <type>` part. Try

```
create function f_rating(budget int) RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
as
begin
if (budget <= 500000) then
    return 'LOW';
else if (budget <= 850000) then
    return 'MID';
else if (budget <= 1200000) then
    return 'HIGH';
else 
    return 'ULTRA';
end #
```

Answer (score 1):

procedure does not return any value, functions do.

Try:

```
create function f_rating(budget int) 
as
```

instead of

```
create procedure f_rating(budget int) 
as
```